# Return statistics from two joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

user:

| userID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mm |
| 2 | ww |
| 3 | tt |

adress:

| userId | street |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | str1 |
| 2 | str3 |
| 3 | str2 |
| 3 | str3 |

I would like to write a query that prints statistics that particular street exist for user

so for str3 I would like to have:

| userID | street present |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | no |
| 2 | yes |
| 3 | yes |

so for str2 I would like to have:

| userID | street present |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | no |
| 2 | no |
| 3 | yes |

so for str1 I would like to have:

| userID | street present |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | no |
| 2 | yes |
| 3 | no |

So far I wrote following query:

```
SELECT distinct(wl.userID), case when wle.street = 'str3' then 'TRUE' end
FROM user wl left JOIN
     adress wle
     on wle.userID = wl.userID;
```

but it generates double results for example for str3 it will print information that both user 2 and 3 have two records: one that str3 is present and one is not.
I would like to print only result that for user str3 is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `exists`!

```
SELECT u.*,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM adress wle
                WHERE wle.userID = wl.userID AND
                      wle.street = 'str3'
               )
       ) as string_flag
FROM user wl;
```

Comment: @Michal there is missing parenthesis:  `)) as string_flag`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `LEFT JOIN` on userID and street name, so that the user table only needs to join/scan the adress (note that the typo on `adress` was in the initial question too) table once for each street.  Use `SELECT distinct` if there is duplicates in the adress table.

```
SELECT wl.userID
      ,CASE WHEN wle.userID IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS str3_present
FROM user wl 
LEFT JOIN  adress wle
    ON  wle.userID = wl.userID
    AND wle.street = 'str3'
```